# Purge video driver installation and set to default values

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, ppa

**this is the (temporary, though) solution I found**

It's not permanent because it's really uncomfortable, but since it was saying me that the nvidia module wasn't loaded, I googled looking for one of those nvidia driver modules that came with ubuntu when I first installed everything. If I'm not mistaken, the drivers that fit my gtx770 are the nvidia 310. So I just purged and reinstalled everything again and then the drivers with `sudo apt-get install nvidia-310` and that made it.

This has some big cons, though. I'm unable to start in X and I need to start a X server from tty (that's where I boot, although I told ubuntu not to do that reverting the only change I did). I can't change to nouveau either, and it works somewhat weird.

Next month I'll keep trying, for now I'm good with this.

---

I'vee been looking for a solution for a bunch of hours and this is what I've tried so far after installing the latest nvidia driver (which boots me to a [black screen with an underscore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162078#162078)). This is my second attempt at doing so and this time I've wronged it even more.

This is what I've done so far:

- Downloaded the driver from the official nvidia page. 340.65, for a GTX 770.
- Changed the system to boot into a tty terminal (in the grub conf file changed the value from 'quiet splash' to 'text').
- Went into a tty terminal, stopped x session and opened the installer .run file.
- It gives me a warning saying the script failed, like the first time I tried, and after also googling this time about it, decided to go with it anyway.
- After rebooting, if I `$sudo service light dm start` it turns into a black screen with an underscore, giving me the error "job start failed" in the terminal I launched it.
- Then, this:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-settings
  sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
  sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-intel
  sudo apt-get install nvidia-common
  sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings
  sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-intel
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl-mesa-dri x-server-xorg-core
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
  sudo apt-get update
  ```

After the apt-get update it gives me an error in the following repositories:

> Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/nouveau/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found
>
> Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/nouveau/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found

(I have an AMD CPU)

I've tried removing the xorg-edgers repository: `sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers/ppa` (also tried it without the "/ppa" as it said when reinstalling the reposityory) but when it's updating packages lists after removing then, it gives me the exact same error back.

I found another command to run a x session, `sudo startx`. After running it, I get a black screeen. Going back to the terminal where I launched it lets me read the error `modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found.` written twice at the end of the screen.

Right now I don't really care anymore about the 340.65 NVidia driver (he). I'm fine with going back to nouveau, but I just can't. I guess I need to fix that repository issue first, but I'm clueless about how to follow with this. I could reinstall the OS but that'd be a huge pain in the ass for me, right now. I'm preparing finals and I have loads of programming libraries installed, so I guess they'll all be gone after that. And, anyway, reinstalling the OS is not something desirable when I somewhat know what's wrong.

Comment: I've noticed over the past few days a lot of people have had issues with ppa 404 errors. Interestingly if you adjust link to show distributions available, older versions are still available. You can always manually remove the ppa listing with a text editor, but that won't help purge the drivers ppa installed

Comment: Remove the card from the machine.  That should revert you back to the on-board graphics.  Then purge everything related to NVidia, then reinsert the card and go back to where you were. (I'm on `nvidia-settings --version

nvidia-settings:  version 346.22  (buildd@lgw01-10)  Tue Dec  9 08:42:45 UTC 2014` and happy with it (for the moment).  If that solves your issue, I'm willing to convert it to an answer...